# How to count successful find (and replace)

Tags: powershell, counter, find-replace

I'm trying to count the number of replacements made by a simple script like so:

```
$count = 0
Function findAndReplace($objFind, $FindText, $ReplaceWith) {
    $count += $objFind.Execute($FindText, $matchCase, $matchWholeWord, \`
             $matchWildCards, $matchSoundsLike, $matchAllWordForms, \`
             $forward, $findWrap, $format, $ReplaceWith, $replace)
}
```

The replacements are done alright, but `$count` remains at `0`...

Comment: you may be counting incorrectly... you may have to use `$count = $count++` or factor in other ways of doing it. (i.e `if ($replacement){$count++}`)

Comment: the `.Execute` Method returns `True` or `Fase` and `$count += $true` does increment correctly. I tried with an `If` statement but with no avail. I'm certainly doing something wrong here...

Comment: No, I'm just trying to increment the counter (True should evaluate to 1 when added to the variable. Basically, I'm just trying to use the boolean returned by the function to count

Comment: @YeO Apologies - still not clear; does it return the string `True` or the boolean `$true`? I assumed the second

Comment: I imagine it returns `$true`. If I let the `Function` return without `> $null` it displays a list of True / False (it prints this way in the console) but that's how `$true` / `$false` evaluate also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a scoping issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-5.1). [AFAIK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AFAIK) `$count` does not have to be initialized first.

The increment logic looks find. However, you will need to return it from the function after the increments. Otherwise it will still be `0` as defined within the scope outside of the function.

```
Function findAndReplace($objFind, $FindText, $ReplaceWith) {
    $count += $objFind.Execute($FindText, $matchCase, $matchWholeWord, \`
             $matchWildCards, $matchSoundsLike, $matchAllWordForms, \`
             $forward, $findWrap, $format, $ReplaceWith, $replace)
    return $count;
}

$myCountOutSideFunctionScope = findAndReplace -objFind ... -FindText ... -ReplaceWith ...
```

Comment: Got it! It works, but it's a bit cumbersome as I have many functions calling each other in cascade so I have to implement counters in every function and return... Is there a way to pipe the output (the boolean) to a counter defined outside the scope ?

Comment: @YeO You could modify the scope of the counter within the function to make it accessible outside of the function - `$script:count =` or `$global:count =`. Then no need to return.

Answer (score 2):

`$count` has to be inside of the function to be used or place it as a parameter.

Try this

```
Function findAndReplace($objFind, $FindText, $ReplaceWith) {
    $count = 0
    $replacementfound = $objFind.Execute($FindText, $matchCase, $matchWholeWord, \`
             $matchWildCards, $matchSoundsLike, $matchAllWordForms, \`
             $forward, $findWrap, $format, $ReplaceWith, $replace)

    if ($replacementfound -eq "True"){$count++}
    write-host $count
}
```